# ASP.NET Boilerplate Datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate Core with Angular 2 version 2.0.2 which still uses the **ngx-bootstrap** theme as supposed to the latest Material theme.

Is there a datepicker built-in or must I follow the [instructions from the old forums](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=17164#p17164) to load bootstrap-datepicker myself?

*On a side-note:* Do the free templates implement the Metronic theme, or is it removed and only available in ASP.NET Zero?

Comment: Free template uses Bsb admin theme (https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/index.html). Check it if has a datepicker. You can use any datepicker library you want. This is our of scope of ABP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ngx-bootstrap** theme used by the old ABP 2.0.2. template does include a datepicker. Follow their [usage example](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) to implement it.

The free templates do not include the Metronic theme.

Answer (score 2):

Datepicker and Metronic are not included in the ASP.NET Boilerplate free template. Metronic is in the [ASP.NET Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/) base solution.

Answer (score 0):

One issue of ngx-bootstrap Datepicker is it is inline, to use the Calendar as popup you can use PrimeNg Calendar input component. Follow the [setup instruction](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) .Then add calender control following [the instruction.](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Boilerplate has a built-in javascript data picker named [moment date picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage)